# how to deploy derived smart contracts solidity

Tags: solidity

If i have a solidity code, which has 2 or 3 contract in it, which depends on each other, How do we deploy such contracts. As when we put this code in browser-solidity, we get different Bytecode and Interface for all the contracts separately. This might be a very stupid question. But how do we deploy these?

1. One by One ?
2. Or is there a way to deploy all at once ?

Example code which i picked from documentation.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract owned {
    function owned() { owner = msg.sender; }
    address owner;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
}


contract mortal is owned {

    function close() onlyOwner {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}

contract priced {

    modifier costs(uint price) {
        if (msg.value >= price) {
            _;
        }
    }
}


contract Register is priced, owned {
    mapping (address => bool) registeredAddresses;
    uint price;

    function Register(uint initialPrice) { price = initialPrice; }

    function register() payable costs(price) {
        registeredAddresses[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    function changePrice(uint _price) onlyOwner {
        price = _price;
    }
}

contract Mutex {
    bool locked;
    modifier noReentrancy() {
        require(!locked);
        locked = true;
        _;
        locked = false;
    }

    function f() noReentrancy returns (uint) {
        require(msg.sender.call());
        return 7;
    }
}
```

The way i deploy the contract:

```
var myContract = web3.eth.contract(ABI);
var contractInstance = myContract.new(
{
    from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: byteCode,
    gas: '4700000'
}, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
})
```

And In this i can put ABI and ByteCode for one one contract at once.

Answer (score 1):

[Truffle](http://truffleframework.com/) makes building, deploying and testing ethereum contracts easy. Install truffle, create a project and deploy. The [example](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-init-bare) generate by `truffle init` shows you how to share code between contracts.